# Having an import error for cannot import name coroutine from asyncio python

Tags: python

The code is giving the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/render/project/src/bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    from database.ia_filterdb import Media

  File "/opt/render/project/src/database/ia_filterdb.py", line 8, in <module>
    from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient

  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/motor/motor_asyncio.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .frameworks import asyncio as asyncio_framework

  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/motor/frameworks/asyncio/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from asyncio import coroutine  # noqa: F401 - For framework interface.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ImportError: cannot import name 'coroutine' from 'asyncio' (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/__init__.py)
```

Please someone suggest the cause for this with correct code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Your Motor version is out of date. You need at least Motor 3.1.1 for Python 3.11 support.